# Hibernate one to one mapping bi directional

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-one

```
public class Driver {

    @OneToOne
    private License license;

    //.. getter setter
};

public class License {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy='license')
    private Driver driver;

   //.. getter setter
}
```

I get a join column license_id in the driver table in Db via this mapping. The problem is that:

```
Driver driver = new Driver();
// save driver then get it etc...

License license = new License();
license.setDriver(driver); 
// save license...

driver.getLicense();
```

Although I set parent from child, the column is still empty and I get null.
How to avoid this?

Comment: After saving license with driver, have you loaded driver with license from database?

Comment: Yes, I did it, but didn't work.

Comment: Well in that case I think I need to look at the full code. Can you post the code for the second portion?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with more descriptive mapping, and we can later remove parts, which will be relaized as defaults anyway.

There is a description which is more verbose than my extract. Please take a look at it:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/

Based on that let's extend the mapping this way:

The driver

```
public class Driver {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name="driver_id")
  private Long driverId;    

  // cascade will do the job for us
  @OneToOne(mappedBy="driver", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  private License license;
```

The license

```
public class License {

  @Id
  @Column(name="driver_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
  @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign"
           , parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="driver"))
  private Long driverId;

  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private Driver driver
  ...
```

When inserting new value, we can set both ends explicitly:

```
Driver driver = new Driver();
License license = new License();
// set both ends
license.setDriver(driver); 
driver.setLicense(license);

// Just save the Driver. the cascade will do the rest
```

And now Hibernate cascading functionality will the the rest for us

Answer (score 0):

looks tacky but try to

```
public void setDriver(Driver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    driver.setLicense(this);
}
```